# rounding specific columns in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 3 columns of data, but I need to round only the first and the last column and the second let as it is. So my "dream" format - round column, not round column, round column.
Could someone help me please?

[image].

Comment: See the duplicate. It's purely a display issue (otherwise you'd be mixing data types: integers and floats). Use `shortG` or `longG`

Comment: Please don’t delete your question after you get help. Instead, accept the answer if it was helpful, and upvote it once you have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

```
A(:,1)=round(A(:,1));
% repeat above line for each column you want.
```

If you have many columns, you may want to store them in an index and loop

```
to_round=[1,3];
for ii in length(to_round)
   A(:,to_round(ii))=round(A(:,to_round(ii)));
end
```